# CLLocation distanceFromLocation: returns zero on iOS 9. Is it a bug?

Tags: ios, geolocation, ios9, core-location

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
-(void)testDistance {
    NSLog(@"Test distance...");

    CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:137.02954600000001 longitude:50.543728999999999];
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:55.79676300 longitude:49.10834400];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2];
    NSLog(@"Distance: %lf", distance);
}
```

iOS 8.4 output:

> Distance: 9021699.415204

iOS 9.1 output:

> Distance: 0.000000

`location1` and `location2` are not nil.

I searched SO for a similar question but couldn't find one. Looks like an iOS 9 bug to me. Do you agree? Do you get similar results? I wanted to send a bug report to Apple but I wanted to confirm first.

I ran the code on simulators (both iOS 8.4 and iOS 9.1). The system language was set to Russian, the region was set to Russia.

**UPDATE:** `lat` and `lon` turned out to be mixed. Latitude should lie in range [-90, 90]. In previous versions of iOS it still produced some result. In iOS 9 they made it return `0`. I don't think that this is a good return value for such case, because it is a perfectly valid value. I think that they should return some error code instead (like they do for `nil`, returning `-1`). At least, it has to be mentioned in the docs. I'm intending to file a bug report in the nearest future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the latitude value of location1 .. I guess there is some mismatch with range of latitude (-90 , 90).

Comment: Didn't quite get what you're suggesting. Could you please explain a bit more? The first latitude is not in range (-90, 90). Besides, I believe, the code is supposed to work for any valid latitude/longtitude pair.

Comment: 137 is the value of latitude of your location1.. Latitude range should be between (-90 <x< 90) where x is the latitude..I checked by swapping your latitude value and longitude value.. I am getting the distance..

Comment: Valid range for latitude is a good point, thank you. Upvoted your answer. I think, I should check the server side of our app. But I still don't think that returning zero is a valid reaction in this case. They return -1 if the argument is nil, so why do they return zero (which is a normal in any way return value) when the input is incorrect?

Comment: Latitude and longitude indeed turned out to be mixed, thank you. But I still don't think that returning zero instead of some special negative error code (like they do for `nil`) is not a good behavior. It should be changed or at least should be mentioned in the documentation. I'll file a bug report some of these days.

Comment: Yes there should be a check around the range of the values instead of returning 0 .. I agree to that..